# pymc3 Conditional deterministic likelihood function

Tags: python, pymc, data-fitting, pymc3, model-fitting

I'm new to `PyMC3` and trying to find a set of parameters that fit data from an experiment. My issue is that my likelihood function is conditional on previous responses of a participant.

The data has the following matrix-form:

```
participant | trial0 | trial1 | ... | trialn
p0 | x | x | ... | x
....
p1 | x | x | ... | x
```

where **x** codifies the participants response in that trial, with values of `0, 1, or 2`. Now, I'm interested in inferring likely parameters for each participant **p**. For simplicity, assume participants may be of one of three types, **t1**, **t2**, **t3**, and that there is a third parameter **l** held constant across these types. I want to infer the likely type of each participant given her behavior across the experiment, the general distribution of types over participants, and the best fit for **l**.

The issue: My likelihood function, call it ***lhs***, is deterministic; plug in the participants type (**t={1,2,3}**), a value for **l**, and the past responses of the participant and it will give you the probability of the observed data **x={0,1,2}** in the current trial. My problem is that I don't know how to tell the PyMC3 model that for each response (**0,1, or 2**) at trial n, the likelihood function depend on the sequence of responses in the trials up to n. I need this because, after each trial, **lhs** is updated by the value of the trial (participants learn in the experiment, so the likelihood of them showing a particular response will change as well.

I'm assuming that there's either a clever way to codify the responses per trial in such a way that the model recursively computes the likelihood function for each response at trial `n > 0`, or that there is a functionality to tell it that data depends on previous data. Alas, I have not been able to find any examples of how either idea may work.

Here's what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

#data is a pandas dataframe where each row
#is a participant, each column a trial, and 
#each cell has value 0,1, or 2.


with pm.Model() as model:
    #Priors
    l = pm.Gamma('lam',10,1.0/0.5) #my prior for the value of l
    p_tau = pm.Dirichlet('p_tau',np.ones(3)) #unbiased prior over types
    tau = pm.Categorical('tau', p=p_tau, shape=3) #distr. over types I want to infer

    #data likelihood function
    lhs = ... #likelihood function; takes l, tau, 
              #and sequentially observed data up to trial n-1 
              #to compute the likelihood of the response of trial n

    #Here's the issue. data would be 0,1,2
    #But lhs should depend on previous trials
    pm.Categorical('obs', p=lhs, observed=data)
```

Suggestions on the model, the data-codification or examples of implemented `PyMC3` models that have similar characteristics would be greatly appreciated.

I left the likelihood unspecified because is quite long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you're trying to do is to infer the probability of a type t1, t2 or t3 for each individual given a sequence of responses (I feel this model might be something like a Markov chain).

It would be helpful to post the likelihood code or some documentation about the model here in order for us to get an idea of how it might be implemented - this will be a bit of a vague answer until I can have a look at the likelihood.

The easiest way to do a conditional in pymc3 is to use Theano's switch op, which is documented here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conditions.html.

Basically switch can be used like: `theano.switch(condition, expression_if_true, expression_if_false)`. You want to use this rather than ifelse in pymc3 likelihoods as switch can be used elementwise but ifelse can't.